# OP's answer is question - We do something?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, answers

If an OP answer is **own** question, does we do something ?

- At first I suggested if we allow moderators to mark that answer as accepted.
- Does we let the system automatically show that answer first in the question windows in case other answer are provided by other user, like if it was accepted.
- We warn the OP that it can accept its own answer at no drawback after he post the answer to is question.
- We change nothing.

Some example:

[proFTPD unable to connect after update ECONNREFUSED](https://serverfault.com/questions/778629/proftpd-unable-to-connect-after-update-econnrefused)

[Wrong IP address registering in DNS](https://serverfault.com/questions/631364/wrong-ip-address-registering-in-dns)

[Configure same Internet Explorer zone mappings with and without ESC via GPO](https://serverfault.com/questions/770595/configure-same-internet-explorer-zone-mappings-with-and-without-esc-via-gpo/770625?noredirect=1#comment972395_770625)

[Windows Server DHCP import/export scopes using netsh.exe](https://serverfault.com/questions/634333/windows-server-dhcp-import-export-scopes-using-netsh-exe)

*An image to show an example too. As I mean a question answered by the one asking it*

---

[image]

---

**NB:** *As the question will stay, I did that major edit to explain my idea, as with my poor English I'am not sure I explained my question correctly at first.*

Comment: _"... to prevent those question to keep getting bumped by the community's user."_ An up/down vote on the answer will stop the community user from bumping the question. If you're tired of seeing the questions bumped, evaluate the answers and vote on them if you feel the answers are either good or bad. No need for a new mechanism for this.

Comment: @Kendra If I do a tag search to answer some questions they are still listed as unanswered, and its obvious they are answered

Comment: They aren't listed as unanswered if one of the answers has an upvote. If none of the answers are worthy of an upvote, then the question is most probably not _really_ answered.

Comment: @Kendra On SF, where the active list of members that help is low, having an answer not upvoted is a reality.

Comment: Why is having an un-upvoted answer an issue to you? Some answers aren't good enough for upvotes and aren't bad enough for downvotes... the point of community bumping them is to see if the answers are worth being voted on, and, if not, hopefully to attract better answers.

Comment: @Catija Never told it was an issue, but Kendra comment told its maybe not a real answer if not upvoted, when actually its the OP itselft told that its the answer.

Comment: If it weren't an issue, I'm pretty sure this question wouldn't exist.

Comment: @Catija I didnt even knew upvote prevent bump.. I just wanted to make the site cleaner, as those question was ontopic but answered by the one asking the help anyhow. Too perfectionist I'am ?

Comment: @Catija To bypass any mod intervention anyhow I can simply downvote those question and answer, the system will purge them if negative

Comment: And if you do that, for that reason you are abusing the voting system.

Comment: @Catija Like upvoting to dont see the bump ?

Comment: Another example seen today; [Why does a DHCP-provided DNS IP address becomes a static one in Windows 10?](http://serverfault.com/questions/779000/why-does-a-dhcp-provided-dns-ip-address-becomes-a-static-one-in-windows-10)

Answer (score 3):

No need for moderator action here. If your only concern is that the question gets bumped, just give it an vote and it will never be bumped again (without edit or new answer).

That is not an action a moderator has to take. You can do that too. So if you see a question getting bumped, give it some attention and vote according your opinion.

We definitely don't want moderators to accept an answer on behalf of someone else.

Comment: You also shouldn't be voting **just** to have the question get out of the community bot's queue... if the answer isn't worthy of a vote, this is a horrid solution... the point of the community bumping is to see if the answers are good or not and if they're either not complete or not supported by evidence or if the question's domain is such that few people can **know** whether the answer is correct or not... it should not be voted on.

Comment: I totally agree @cat

Comment: Did you checked the example I gave before answering ? An answer from the one asking help "Turns out it was something quite similar to that - see my answer....  ", but his own answer not accepted.

Answer (score -1):

The reason I think your request would not be a good idea is because what if that answer does not solve the question? Checked questions mean that that is the solution to the user's problem, and many times the user might not find that answer as a helpful one.

Also note that there already is a few reminders. For example, there is one on your profile page, where it says in red text something like **"Have you considered accepting an answer?"**. Also, when you upvote an answer as an OP, you get a message **"Don't forget to accept by ticking the green box"**.

---

This was some side information and a bit of a background. Your question was about the moderator being able to accept an OP's answer if it's his own. In my opinion, OP's own answers should be a provisional placeholder until a better answer is provided. Of course, you can change the accept at any time, but I think the feature would be superfluous.

Comment: Did you checked the example I gave before answering ? An answer from the one asking help "Turns out it was something quite similar to that - see my answer.... ", but his own answer not accepted.

Comment: @yagmoth555 I'll then edit my answer. In my opinion, this should still not be possible. Sometimes, the answer is provisional, until a better is provided. Apart from that, I would consider it superfluous